# How to convert a character column of data frame to Posixlt type

Tags: r

One of the column of data.frame is "character"
Ex:   9:56:53 PM 3/31/2012

```
/> class(columnName)  
[1] "character"

/>ttable[,c(3)] <- as.POSIXlt(ttable[,c(3)],tz="GMT", format="%H:%M:%S %p %m/%d/%Y")    

/>class(columnName)     
[1] "numeric"
```

I expect it to be posixlt but it turns out to be numeric. How to make it posixlt ?

If i apply the same instruction on actual value of the columns it works as expected ?

```
/> dd <- as.POSIXlt("9:56:53 PM 3/31/2012",tz="GMT", format="%H:%M:%S %p %m/%d/%Y")  

/> class(dd)  
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Are you doing something like `columnName <- ttable[,3]; ttable[,3] <- as.POSIXlt(...); class(columnName)`? In that case, note that `columnName` is not changed when `ttable[,3]` is because R doesn't work like that. You can either convert `columnName` directly, or *after* you convert `ttable[,3]` then do `columnName` <- `ttable[,3]` and re-test its class. (Also, is `ttable` a data frame or matrix/array?)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee ColumnName is just to indicate the name of the column. No operation was performed on the column name. Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's create some data and replicate your problem. Note the warning, which you did not mention:

```
ttable <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2, z="9:56:53 PM 3/31/2012",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ttable
#   x y                    z
# 1 1 1 9:56:53 PM 3/31/2012
# 2 2 2 9:56:53 PM 3/31/2012
ttable[, c(3)] <- as.POSIXlt(ttable[,c(3)], tz="GMT",
                                            format="%H:%M:%S %p %m/%d/%Y") 
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , c(3), value = list(sec = c(53, 53 :
#   provided 9 variables to replace 1 variables
sapply(ttable, class)
#         x         y         z 
# "integer" "integer" "numeric"
```

As @joran pointed us to `?DateTimeClasses`, the problem is that `as.POSIXlt` returns a list of vectors of length nine (sec, min, hour, etc.). This list cannot be assigned in place of `ttable[,c(3)]` because its current "width" is 1. Instead, the whole data.frame column (or list element) must be reassigned, via `ttable[[3]]` or `ttable$z`:

```
ttable <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2, z="9:56:53 PM 3/31/2012",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ttable[[3]] <- as.POSIXlt(ttable[,c(3)], tz="GMT",
                                         format="%H:%M:%S %p %m/%d/%Y") 
sapply(ttable, class)
# $x
# [1] "integer"
# 
# $y
# [1] "integer"
# 
# $z
# [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Assigning a list as a column of a data.frame is not a very common thing to do. This similar example may help:

```
ttable[, 1] <- list(a = 1:3, b = 3:1)
# Warning messages: [...]
ttable$x <- list(a = 1:3, b = 3:1)
#         x y                   z
# 1 1, 2, 3 1 2012-03-31 09:56:53
# 2 3, 2, 1 2 2012-03-31 09:56:53
```

Comment: Scan through `?DateTimeClasses` for a partial explanation.